# two similar div elements one with an additional class how to ovewrite colour on descending elements?

Tags: css, css-selectors

The first div looks like this

```
<div class="item ui-droppable  feed masonry-brick">
```

The second one has an additional class small

I would like to modify the descending element when the class selector is small and change the color to black /properties of those items .

I have tried the following with no success:

```
 .item .more .deliverytype {
    color: red;
    display: inline;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
    position: absolute;
    right: 7px;
    text-align: right;
    top: 54px;
}


  .small .deliverytype {
    color: black;important!

}
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/SRzkw/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just be more specific - no need for `!important`, just use `.small.item`.

```
.small.item .more .deliverytype {
    color: black;
}
```

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/xvNUe/) - it works.

Since `color:red` was being set via `.item .more .deliverytype`, you just needed to add in `.small`. Therefore if the parent contains both `.small` and `.item` (`.small.item`), it would style the `.deliverytype` which is a descendant of `.more`.

Comment: As a side note, your original code was working - you just used `!important` wrong.. see http://jsfiddle.net/epn8w/